# Visual Studio Add-in/Tool for Reporting xml-doc coverage?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml-documentation

I was wondering if there existed a tool that would give you some sort of report about what percentage of your code base has doc-comments and highlight where you might want to add some.  Sort of like code coverage tools for unit-testing work.  Probably I can write an FxCop or Resharper rule to enforce xml-doc comments on public methods/fields/classes...

Comment: Asking tools are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Since when?  99% of the time when you search for information on an add-in, the second page after the add-in's homepage is a stackoverflow question.